# How can I get custom querystring included in returned firebase dynamic shortlink

Tags: firebase, url, firebase-dynamic-links, query-string, url-shortener

I'm using the Firebase dynamic link post API to return a shortlink. When I post this:

`https://CENSORED.page.link/?link=https://www.CENSORED.co.uk/offers/friends/?utm_source=referafriend&utm_medium=ecrm&utm_campaign=cbk25&utm_term=988776`

clicking the returned shortlink redirects to:

`https://www.CENSORED.co.uk/offers/friends/?utm_source=referafriend`

The post is made from clientside js. Firebase is returning a working shortlink, but with some parameters missing.

Expected url from clicked shortlink:

`https://www.CENSORED.co.uk/offers/friends/?utm_source=referafriend&utm_medium=ecrm&utm_campaign=cbk25&utm_term=988776`

Looks like its chopping off most of my querystring - how do I get the full query string returned correctly please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: Escaping the url worked for me:

params lost:

`"https://www.test.co.uk/testing/?utm_source=jam&utm_medium=spoon&utm_campaign=jar&utm_term=lid"`

params returned correctly:

`"https%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.co.uk%2Ftesting%2F%3Futm_source%3Djam%26utm_medium%3Dspoon%26utm_campaign%3Djar%26utm_term%3Dlid"`